# Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'OracleNotification'

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, hp-uft

I'm currently using UFT 12.50 build 3785.
With the following addins:

- Java
- Oracle
- Qt
- Visual Basic
- Web

The following function is stored within my function library in UFT:

```
Public Function getMessage()     
    MsgBox OracleNotification("Decision").GetROProperty("message")    
End Function
```

When I call it in my Action1 as follows:

```
getMessage()
```

or

```
Call getMessage()
```

or

```
getMessage
```

I get the following error:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'OracleNotification'

But when I call the required code directly in Action1 as follows:

```
MsgBox OracleNotification("Decision").GetROProperty("message")
```

Then it executes as required.

I have many other Oracle methods in my function library that are executing without any issues. (OracleButton, OracleTextfield, OracleCheckbox, etc)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by changing the function as follows:

```
Public Function getMessage()     
     MsgBox OracleApplications("class description:=application").OracleNotification("Decision").GetROProperty("message")    
End Function
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer, if it suits your needs :)

Comment: Just have to wait 24 hours after I posted it. :P